# как вывести данные в разные переменные из одного массива

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

есть массив из двух единиц данных, он получен из бд sql, первое значение выводится у меня таким образом, подскажите как вывести второе.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, id FROM Table WHERE nameAxt = '" +axt + "'", conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();    
while (reader.Read())
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
conn.Close();

private void listbox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    axtit = listbox2.Text;
}
```

в общем значение name я получаю из listbox2.Text а как мне получить значение id при которое ему соответствует? то есть

```
id       name
1         aaa
2         bbb
3         ccc
4         ddd
```

положим в listbox я выбрал строчку ccc мне нужно чтобы в некую переменную было присвоено значение id равное 3.

В общем додумался только до такого решения, создать отдельный строковый массив из значений "id"

```
 {
      listBox2.Items.Add(read.GetValue(0).ToString()); 
      string v = read.GetValue(1).ToString();
      string[] nums = new[] { v };
 }
```

я так думаю что используя значение tabindex listbox2 из массива можно получить нужное мне значение, теперь вопрос, как из строкового массива по индексу записать значение в переменную? Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
kod = listBox2.TabIndex;
string kod1 = new string (nums[kod]);
```

ругается что "Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из char в char*" я так понял что проблема в том что я пытаюсь получить единичное значение, как исправить?

Comment: `read.GetValue(1)`?

Comment: мне нужны оба значения именно после выбора name в listbox.

Comment: ну так берите оба, в чем проблема?

Comment: ну как его вывести, я только учусь, недопонимаю как это сделать, подскажите буду очень благодарен

Comment: я думаю, вы вообще начали не с того. Вы же с WPF работаете, пользуйтесь MVVM .

Comment: у меня проект практически готов, просто подскажите как мне это сделать и все

Comment: ну если хотите себе в ноги стрелять, вам надо сделать класс (со свойствами, что вам надо, типа id и name), который вы будете хранить в листбоксе и настроить биндинги на нужные поля класса в xaml (см DataTemplate). Пример есть тут https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/

Comment: Вы этот код выдумали чтоли? Он был совсем не похож на то, что компилируется. Я поправил.

Comment: да руками набирал, мозг за день уже устал конкретно, смотрю и понять не могу что не так, спасибо что поправили.